# Google Speech API cannot import name 'enums'

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use Google Speech API to recognize speech, on windows with colab

here is the error
ImportError: cannot import name 'enums' from 'google.cloud.speech_v1'
Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: What is the version of the client library you have installed? You can run `! pip freeze | grep google-cloud-speech` in a code cell to get the version. Also, can you share the code you are executing and the documentation you referred to?

Comment: Hello. Can you upvote and accept my answer if it addresses your question? If not let me know so that it can be improved. Accepting an answer will help other community members with their research as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like in the new version they have removed `enums`. Check this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#enums-and-types), If you want `enums` then you have to switch to an old version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in **@addno1**'s answer, `enums` and `types` have been removed in the 2.x versions of the library. It seems that you are using a 2.x version of the library, hence the error.

If your code is using the 1.x version of the library and if you would like to upgrade to the latest version of the library, refer to this [migration guide](https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/2.13.0/UPGRADING.html)(same mentioned in the other answer). You can refer to this [quick start](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-client-libraries) for setup instructions and an updated client library code given below.

```py
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import speech


# Instantiates a client
client = speech.SpeechClient()

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
gcs_uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/speech/brooklyn_bridge.raw"

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)

config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code="en-US",
)

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

for result in response.results:
    print("Transcript: {}".format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
```

If you want to use the older code, you will have to downgrade the library version to `1.3.2` (last 1.x version) by running the `pip` command

```
pip install google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
```